# Go back to specified screens only using back botton in android

Tags: android

App having screen1, screen2, screen3 , screen4

user can go to screen3 from remaining 3screens

if user clicks on back button in screen3

then he should be redirected to screen1(if he comes from screen1) or screen2 (if he comes from screen2)

but should not go to screen4

i tried finish()  in screen3

functionality is missing

how can i solve this,
please help me 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you launched screen3 from screen4 and did finish() in screen4, then you clicked back button from screen3 and got back to screen4????

Comment: sorryyyy
i used finish() in screen3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look into Intent flags.  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY can be used so that you can't go back to an activity.

> public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the
>   user navigates away from it, the activity is finished. This may also
>   be set with the noHistory attribute.

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
in screen4 i am using this
it works fine.